# When paginating a Page with the <!--nextpage--> tag, how can the 2nd and subsequent page styles be customised?

Tags: posts, functions, pages, pagination, wp-link-pages

I want to apply different styles for a *second page* in `single.php` or posts. How can I do this?

I have the following code in `single.php` to split the page in two parts:

```
<!--nextpage-->
```

If there is a different method to add another "tab" to post or the like, I am grateful for any help… I just want to add a "custom page" to my post – like a gallery for a post – so the URL could be like this:

```
http://localhost/mysite/1024/postname/gallery/
http://localhost/mysite/1024/postname/custom-page/
```

Code in `single.php`:

```
    <?php get_header();?>
 <main>
<?php get_sidebar() ?>

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post">

            <div class="top-single-movie">

            <div class="info">  
            <h3 class="title" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark">
            <?php the_title(); ?></a>
            <?php if( get_field('date') ): ?>
             ( <?php the_field('date'); ?> )
            <?php endif; ?> 
            </h3>
            </div>


            <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) :
            the_post_thumbnail('medium');
            else : 
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/img/default.png">';
            endif;
            ?>

            </div><!-- End. top-single-movie -->


            <?php the_content(); ?>

            <?php 
    wp_link_pages( array(
        'before' => '<div class="page-link"><span>' . __( 'Pages:', 'tl_back' ) . '</span>',
        'after' => '</div>'
    ) ); 
?>

            <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/php/single/tv-single-rand.php'); ?>


            </div><!-- End. content-single-movie -->


            <p class="tags"><?php the_tags(); ?> </p> 



            <!--?php comments_template(); // Get comments.php template ?-->


            <?php endwhile; else: ?>
            <p> <?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?> </p>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <!-- END Loop -->


            <ul class="navigationarrows"> 
            <li class="previous">
            <?php previous_post_link('&laquo; %link'); ?>
            <?php if(!get_adjacent_post(false, '', true)) 
            { echo '<span>&laquo;Previous</span>'; } ?>
            </li>
            <li class="next">
            <?php next_post_link('%link &raquo;'); ?>
            <?php if(!get_adjacent_post(false, '', false)) { echo '<span>Next post:</span>'; } ?> 
            </li>
            </ul><!-- end . navigationarrows --> 

    </div>

 </main>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress already adds classes to the body for you to handle this, as long as your theme correctly uses the body_class template tag.

On the 2nd page of Page, your body will have these additional classes: `paged`, `paged-2` & `page-paged-2`, so you can see that you can make changes to styles to suit:

```
body.page {
    background: black;
    color: white;
}

body.paged {
    background: green;
    color: red;
}
```

Core achieves this with this logic:

```
global $wp_query;

$page = $wp_query->get( 'page' );

    if ( ! $page || $page < 2 )
        $page = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );

    if ( $page && $page > 1 && ! is_404() ) {
        $classes[] = 'paged-' . $page;

        if ( is_single() )
            $classes[] = 'single-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_page() )
            $classes[] = 'page-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_category() )
            $classes[] = 'category-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_tag() )
            $classes[] = 'tag-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_date() )
            $classes[] = 'date-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_author() )
            $classes[] = 'author-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_search() )
            $classes[] = 'search-paged-' . $page;
        elseif ( is_post_type_archive() )
            $classes[] = 'post-type-paged-' . $page;
}
```

You could adapt this logic within your templates if you wanted to use different HTML on the first & subsequent pages.

Comment: Where do I add this code?

Comment: The CSS goes in your stylesheet. The PHP is an example for you to develop your own code from.

Comment: sorry for my question the php code adding to my function.php ? because when adding to my single.php in not worked

Comment: The PHP is an example. What is it you want it to do?

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the post ID, you can target that specific body with custom CSS. For example, if your custom page has an id of 99, you can set up a custom stylesheet and prefix all the selectors with:

body.postid-99

Obviously, this is depending on your theme. If your theme uses a different class in the body tag ( not .postid-99 ) you would have to change the selector accordingly.

...or...

Enqueue the right stylesheet in your theme functions. for example:-

```
function my_enqueue_scripts(){
    wp_register_style( 'my-css', "my-stylesheet.css" );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-css' );
}

if ( get_the_ID() == 99 )
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts');
```

Ive not checked the above code but hopefully it helps you get where you need to be.

Comment: While that answers the question of how to style a post or page differently to others, I think the OP wants a different layout for page 2 of a post that's broken up with the <!-- nextpage -->

Comment: Ah... I misunderstood. I saw the word "style" and made assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to create a different template to a new page.

If that's the case, you need to duplicate the single.php of your theme (preferably in a child theme) and use the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) to override the default single.php with the new one.

1. Get the ID of the page you want to do this
2. Duplicate the file single.php and rename to single-ID.php, changing "ID" with the page id
3. Now you can edit the single-ID.php and the changes will only apply to that page.

If you want to apply to more than one page you could create a new template and add a name to it. Then you'd select it in the page edit in all the pages you want, instead of doing it by id. This would depend on the theme you are using.

Comment: That's the same as @MichaeMichael 's answer, but without a code example.  It also doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Maybe it didn't answer but it's not the same.
@MichaeMichael 's answer only applys to CSS. What I answered makes it possible to change the PHP not only CSS.

Comment: Ah true, sorry!